# Proc transpose extra columns?

Tags: sas

I have a set of data where I pull the id and reason_cd. There can be multiple reasons and hence there are duplicate Id's. I want to transpose this to give one row per Id and multiple columns for the reasons.

Using the below works. However two columns pop for *Name* and *Label* and the value for every Id is 'reason_cd'. Why are these there and can they be removed without doing another data step to drop them?

```
proc transpose data=aars out=test prefix=decline_reason;
by ID;
var reason_cd;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The _NAME_ variable has the name of the original variable (useful when you are using PROC TRANSPOSE to go the other way from many variables to many rows).  The _LABEL_ variable will only appear if one or more of the transposed variables has a label attached.

So use the DROP= dataset option to remove the _NAME_ variable.  Using a LABEL statement to remove the label from the variable will remove the _LABEL_ variable.

```
proc transpose data=aars out=test(drop=_name_) prefix=decline_reason;
  by ID;
  var reason_cd;
  label reason_cd=' ';
run;
```

If you need more control use a data step to code your our transpose algorithm.

```
data want;
  do index=1 to 4 until(last.id);
    set aars end=eof; 
    by id; 
    array decline_reason [4] 8; 
    decline_reason[index]=reason_cd; 
  end; 
  drop reason_cd index ;
run;
```

If REASON_CD is character instead of numeric than change the length specification that the ARRAY statement will use to create the new variables from 8 to a $ followed by the length needed.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! There can be up to 4 records for each ID. But sometimes there are less. Is there a way to always have place holders for 4 variables? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Updated to include example of data step that will always create 4 variables.